# How to show view all posts from front page?

Tags: posts

I have a front page and there also some posts in blog section. After some posts there is a link view all Posts. How to dynamic this view all posts with specific page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's partially depends upon your themes functions or plugin like Visual Composer.

On the other hand, there is some plugins - [Display Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/display-posts-shortcode/) or [Yearly Archive](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-yearly-archive/), which can display all the posts.

or

Create a custom page template and include the following code

```
<?php 
// the query
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'post', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>

<?php if ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<ul>

    <!-- the loop -->
    <?php while ( $wpb_all_query->have_posts() ) : $wpb_all_query->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- end of the loop -->

</ul>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```